# How to get data from multiple tables in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, join

I have tables:

```
table specs
column: profession_id
column: id

table prof
column: id
```

I have succesfully received data from single prof and listed it's children (specs)

```
Profession.joins(:specializations).find_by_slug(params[:id])
```

But now I have two more tables:

```
table docs
column: id

table docs_specs
column: docs_id
column: specs_id
```

So, table docs and specs are connected.
How can I get single prof, with it's children specs (already working), and "docs" children of each specs. A bit complex huh ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something lime this:

```
Profession.where(:id >= params[:id]).joins(:specs => {:docs_specs => :docs})
```